# Unable to use two flex across two columns in a row in Tailwind

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I have the following table object below. I want to apply flex-wrap such that, if the text is too long (like the one highlighted below), the text element will be wrapped using flex-wrap.

[image]

So, I use this code:

```
<div className="mt-8 flow-root">
<div className="-my-2 -mx-4 overflow-x-auto sm:-mx-6 lg:-mx-8">
    <div className="inline-block min-w-full py-2 align-middle sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
        <div className="overflow-hidden shadow ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 sm:rounded-lg">
        <table className="min-w-full divide-y divide-gray-300">
            <thead className="bg-gray-50">
                ....
            </thead>
            <tbody className="divide-y divide-gray-200 bg-white">
                {questionList.map((question) => (                                                   
                    <tr className="hover:bg-gray-50">

                        ..... 
                        
                        <td className="whitespace-nowrap px-3 py-4 text-sm flex text-gray-500">
                            {question.roles.map((role) => (
                                <span>
                                    {role}{' '}
                                </span>
                            ))}
                        </td>
                        <td className="relative whitespace-nowrap py-4 pl-3 pr-4 text-right text-sm font-medium sm:pr-6 flex gap-x-2">                                        
                            {question.interview.map((company) => (
                                <span>
                                    <Image
                                        alt={company}
                                        width={50}
                                        height={50}
                                        className="mx-auto rounded-full h-6 w-6 sm:h-8 sm:w-8" 
                                        src={`/company_logos/${company}_logo.png`}
                                    />
                                </span> 
                            ))}
                        </td>
                        
                    </tr>              
                ))}
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

The code above introduces flex in the role column and company column. However, when I apply the flex tags, the company gets shifted below the role column. What's happening here and how do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a minimal and complete example that can reproduce your issue? I've noticed that you use both `white-nowrap` which is often used when you DON'T want the text to wrap, you can try remove that and see if that works

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question , you want the `role` field to wrap in it's cell if its long .

You can try using `flex` with `flex-shrink-0`

**Output:**

[image]

**Minimum reproducible code:**

```
<table class=" ">
  <tbody class="">
    <tr class="flex items-center gap-3 hover:bg-gray-50">
      <td class="flex-shrink-0">This is the title</td>
      <td class="flex-shrink-0 rounded-3xl bg-blue-500 p-1">Difficult</td>
      <td class="px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">Hi role this is role comparitively a bigger one and still bigger it is gonna be and still big</td>
      <td class="flex flex-shrink-0 gap-2 p-4">
        <span>
          <image alt="company" width="50" height="50" class="mx-auto h-6 w-6 rounded-full sm:h-8 sm:w-8" src="/img/beams.jpg" />
        </span>
        <span>
          <image alt="company" width="50" height="50" class="mx-auto h-6 w-6 rounded-full sm:h-8 sm:w-8" src="/img/beams.jpg" />
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**[Tailwind-play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/TtOJOLTJhh)**